# How to deal with big project in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF environment and I am experiencing some problems like if there are alots of things how do we manage them.for example I have three borders each of same size same location and they contains controls like textboxes etc etc we construct them sequentially but when it comes to edit we get in trouble modifying the border that is at bottom.

So in short how do we manage many controls on single page so that it remains easy to edit

Comment: I know this sounds simple, but if you have too many controls on a page to maintain, you probably have too many controls.  One thing you can do is to break related things into individual Views (or UserControls), and then just put the individual Views on your page.

Comment: What do you mean, "we construct them sequentially"?  That makes it sound like you're constructing your UI procedurally in code instead of declaratively in XAML.  If so, well, there's a big part of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand your concerns, but here are several point that make editing WPF UI pretty easy:

1. **Correct usage of layout panels**. If you will use approach with absolute positions for each control then it might become a nightmare to move or resize some of your controls. Correct layout (and panels such as `DockPanel/StackPanel/etc`) might help you a lot.
2. **Incapsulating repeatable parts**. WPF has a lot of feature to avoid repeating UI code. I'm talking mostly about `Styles` and `Control templates` at the moment. If you have your borders repeating through the entire window, maybe you should think on extracting this border as a `ControlTemplate` for `ContentControl` for example?

Answer (score 1):

but I've found that encapsulating controls such as borders, textboxes etc in **User Controls** helps to keep things well managed (not to mention helps reduce code), similarly using a Resource Dictionary to store styles/animations is useful for very big projects (remember though that the local resources will take precedence when applied so remove them if they not in use)

furthermore, using Layout Panels such as **Stacks,Grids and Dockpanels** allows you to collapse User Controls when not needed or otherwise (also I've found that for some reason, Grids allow controls to overlap (when items are not correctly ordered in Grid Rows and Columns) which can lead to some elements not being seen in design.

Plan your layout properly and think through which Panels would be best for them, having to go back much later and change can be annoying (though admittedly it happens).

Also remember to use partial classes to properly structure your stuff, having to read through 1000+ lines of code to find something can be a nightmare.